# Цветокоррекция изображения в header

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, цвета

Всем привет.

Начинаю верстать макет и столкнулся с одной проблемой: цветокор фонового изображения в секции `header` не совсем соответствует картинке в Photoshop (см.скриншоты).

В самом макете изображение немного темнее (и при этом насыщеннее, что ли) благодаря Rectangle 1 (обведено кружочком).

Пробовал накинуть на само изображение слой с `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);`, но это не то.

Хочу понять, как добиться (почти)полного совпадения. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может фильтры помогут? filter: saturate(200%)

Comment: А как вы сделали то в итоге? Как изображение выглядит без фильтров?

Comment: Можно просто из фотошопа картинку с фильтрами вырезать =) или это спортивный интерес?

Comment: Изображение без фильтров выглядит как на первом скриншоте.

Comment: @Skywave, можно, но я не знаю, как. Да и хотелось понять, как это с помощью CSS провернуть )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Растрируйте изображение в фотошопе, и вырежьте как обычную картинку.

Отметьте оба слоя -> Правый клик по слою -> преобразить в смарт-объект -> растрировать слой.

При сохранении для web (ctrl + shift + alt + s) поставьте галку "преобразовать в sRGB", чтобы цвета не потемнели. :)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Запомню на будущее :)

Answer (score 0):

Из вопроса не ясно какие параметры смешивания слоёв установлены, но "на глаз" можно попробовать добится похожего результата используя [CSS фильтры](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/filter).